# Enabling syncookies in /proc not working

Tags: linux, syn

I'm trying to enable syncookies by echoing '1' in de /proc file like this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies
```

*(I also tried it with quotes, without whitespace "1>/proc...")*

However after running this command, there is still a '0' in the file...

```
root# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies 
0
```

[image]

Changing other /proc files causes no problems.

**Shell version:**

```
4.3.30(1)-release
```

**Distro:**

```
Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid

root:~# uname -a
Linux xxxxx 2.6.32-29-pve #1 SMP Thu Apr 24 10:03:02 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What is causing this? I get no error message and have sudo (root) rights.

Comment: what is the command you used? maybe you used so in front?

Comment: The command was the one above in the post. Echoing that "1" in de proc file.

Comment: are you using sudo?

Comment: Yes, also when I try to edit other proc files, that works perfectly.

Comment: loging as root and use your previous command "sudo su -" and after this "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies"

Comment: I'm already logged in as root. But just to make sure I just tried it by first doing "sudo su -" and still the same.

Comment: Which distro and which shell versions?

Comment: have you tried without double quote, because you need to write an integer, using double quotes you are writing an string.

Comment: You need to update your question with the exact kernel version you are using. Otherwise we would not be able to reproduce the problem. Also you need to tell us what shell you are using. In bash using `echo 1 >` works, but `echo 1>` does not work. Without knowing which shell it is, we couldn't point exactly what subtleties there might be. It is also possible something else is changing the setting between echo and your cat commands. You could try executing both from the same command line to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Updated the post with shell and distro version. Also when I change other /proc files, this works perfect.

Comment: If you run `dmesg` does the output contain any clues?

Comment: Contains the following: `device eth0 entered promiscuous mode - 
device eth0 left promiscuous mode ...`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could think of now is that your kernel was not compiled with the option `CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES`, because the default value of `tcp_syncookies` is 1.
Try to check this option.

Else try to use `sysctl` (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1`).

Comment: When executing that command, I get the following output:
`net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1`. But when I cat the /proc file, there still is a zero in it...

Comment: @chiodos And what about the CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES ?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Hum... Ok depends on you kernel/distro (you should provide the output of `uname -a` instead of just distro name). Usually you can find kernel compile options in /proc/config.gz or in /boot/config-kernel-version: `zgrep COOKIES /proc/config.gz`

Comment: Updated post. None of these two files exists

Comment: Then I can't help you more. Just a bit strange that you use a debian sid with a squeeze kernel...